# Model definition from meta file tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph

I am using python3.6 and tensorflow.

Can I see a model definition from the .meta file? So, seeing a graph with all the operations that will be computed when the model is run.

Comment: you can see the model definition from tensor board but I don't know whether that serves  your purpose